# Textarea issues when retrieving data with line breaks inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

A lot of queries raised targeting this issue. i.e. line breaks within a textarea attribute.

I tried to use `str_replace("<br />", "\n",$text)` within a javascript variable where I got it working within a php code. Unfortunatley had no such luck with the methodology I am using within the javascript code.

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
var markup = "<textarea name='tcaction[]' id='tcaction' rows='3' cols='105' placeholder='Enter Required Actions' required><?php echo str_replace("<br />", "\n",$text) ?></textarea><br>";
```

The str_replace within the javascript variable is not working. Would you cordially direct me to the right direction?

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: You are missing either proper quoting of quotes or string concatenation... you can actually SEE it from the syntay highlighting, that something is wrong with your string..

Comment: Oh, and if you do it that way, any unescaped newline will break the javascript again... and if it works, it's an XSS loophole :)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Tell us the behavior or a specific error if there is

Answer (score 0):

Replace this ...

```
...<?php echo str_replace("<br />", "\n",$text) ?>...
                                     ^^
```

... by this:

```
...<?php echo str_replace("<br />", "\\n",$text) ?>...
                                     ^^^
```

So PHP sends `\n` (2 chars) and JavaScript interprets it as newline character.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck in there. Works like a charm in php but cannot make it work here.

Answer (score -1):

All, for the interest of others the issue has been resolved as follows:

`var text = <?php echo json_encode($text); ?>`

and then used

`text.replace("<br />", "\n");`

it works and no issues of un-escaped new line etc etc.

thanks anyway.